# Liferay Build Service Exception

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, ant, liferay-6, icefaces-3

I'm developing an application with eclipse and liferay.

When I run the build-service to create all classes for my db, ant throws this:

```
    Buildfile: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build.xml
build-service:
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar.manifest
     [java] Java Result: 1
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Datos%20y%20Programas/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3-Tomcat/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Datos%20y%20Programas/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3-Tomcat/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Datos%20y%20Programas/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3-Tomcat/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
     [echo] Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.language.LanguageUtil' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.language.LanguageImpl#7c08a22' of type [com.liferay.portal.language.LanguageImpl] while setting bean property 'language'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.language.LanguageImpl#7c08a22' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.ArrayApplicationContext.<init>(ArrayApplicationContext.java:31)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.spring.util.SpringUtil._loadContext(SpringUtil.java:74)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.spring.util.SpringUtil.loadContext(SpringUtil.java:60)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.util.InitUtil.initWithSpring(InitUtil.java:189)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.util.InitUtil.initWithSpring(InitUtil.java:166)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:198)
     [echo] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.language.LanguageImpl#7c08a22' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
     [echo]     ... 20 more
     [echo] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findMethod(BeanUtils.java:162)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
     [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
     [echo]     ... 23 more
     [echo] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext
     [echo]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     [echo]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [echo]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [echo]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [echo]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
     [echo]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [echo]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
     [echo]     ... 31 more

BUILD FAILED
C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin.xml:248: Service Builder generated exceptions.

Total time: 8 seconds
```

I have reviewed all google, liferay posts, this site, and so on, and I’m not able to find an answer to this.
All help you can give me to solve this issue is going to be appreciated.

Eclise Luna

Some other info:

```
<dependencies defaultconf="default">
        <dependency name="icefaces" org="org.icefaces" rev="3.3.0" />
        <dependency name="icefaces-ace" org="org.icefaces" rev="3.3.0" />
        <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
        <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
        <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
    <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="jsp-api" rev="2.0"/>
    <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="servlet-api" rev="2.4"/>
    </dependencies>
```

I added those sugested libraries and now I Have this:

```
Buildfile: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build.xml
build-service:
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar.manifest
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\build-service-classpath.jar
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Datos%20y%20Programas/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3-Tomcat/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Datos%20y%20Programas/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3-Tomcat/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/C:/Datos%20y%20Programas/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3-Tomcat/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
     [echo] java.lang.NullPointerException
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncStringReader.<init>(UnsyncStringReader.java:34)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.util.xml.XMLSafeReader.<init>(XMLSafeReader.java:25)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:437)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.SAXReaderUtil.read(SAXReaderUtil.java:155)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._getContentDocument(ServiceBuilder.java:1734)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.getContent(ServiceBuilder.java:121)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:631)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:229)
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
      [zip] Warning: skipping zip archive C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet-service.jar because no files were included.
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Datos y Programas\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\EGGSOFT_PM-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 40 seconds
```

But no class where created, and It throws a new exception: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Could you please share your service.xml?

Comment: And make sure you have it in <portlet-path>\docroot\WEB-INF\service.xml

Answer (score 1):

Corrupted Liferay SDK.

I uncompress agnain the SDK, and now works.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have all needed dependencies in your classpath. If you're using Maven (and if not - I strongly recommend you to migrate) just add this to your pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Done.

Comment: Done, but a new exception.